# Is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} b_{m} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} a_{n} b_{m}$ correct?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Since we have $\sum_{n=0}^{m} a_{n} \sum_{i=0}^{k} b_{i} = \sum_{n=0}^{m}  \sum_{i=0}^{k} a_{n} b_{i}$.

Is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} b_{m} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} a_{n} b_{m}$ correct ?

Comment: Yes, if $\sum_na_n$ and $\sum_mb_m$ both converge.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Converge or Converge absolutely?

Comment: @Arjang. Converge....................

Comment: @DanielWainfleet : so this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product requires correction? Look at the convergence section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean exactly what you wrote, then yes, because the inner sum on the two sides are the same:
$$
a_{n} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} b_{m} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} a_{n} b_{m}
$$
for any $n$, since $a_n$ does not depend on $m$.

But it's not necessarily the case that we can sum the quantities $a_nb_m$ in any order we want and arrive at $\sum_{n=0}^{m} a_{n} \sum_{i=0}^{k} b_{i}$. (It would be true if, for example, these two sums converged absolutely.)

Comment: Then $(a_{0}+a_{1}+\cdots)(b_{0}+b_{1}+\cdots) = a_{0}(b_{0}+b_{1}+\cdots)+a_{1}(b_{0}+b_{1}+\cdots)+\cdots$ ? The RHS seems very weird.